# Raspberry pi with openvpn for a 5 user office can work?

Tags: networking, openvpn

My company have a lot of small offices around the world with between 1 and 10 employees and when they need vpn access to our network we have been using small barebone PC with Linux to work as router/Firewall/VPN.

We are going to try in one of the office to replace a barebone pc for raspberry and see how it goes. Anybody have tried something like this?

I have done some I/O test with CPU stressed 100% at the same time and it worked fine  reaching only 60ºC with 1ghz overclook. I've read about people using the pi for Netflix over a VPN and it handled it perfectly.

The overclook is just for test purposes, once in production it will work with the default speed and 2 SD (cloned content) will be send for the problems with SD corruption

Before I send it oversees I would like to do a stress test of the VPN, any suggestions on how to do it?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is a classic case of 'Don't do that'. This is a terrible idea.

Comment: I love when people say it's a bad idea but not why ^^

Comment: It's simple really. RPis are not designed for this they are a tool for enthusiasts and education. That you have to overclock it to make it performant is also a red flag and will likely lead to data corruption and no end of pain. Instead of focussing on the CPU focus on the data. Setup a lab and run simulated usage through it and see what happens.

Comment: Oh, lets start with the most critical part of your question - the stress test - Openvpn talks about how to do it on their website. As for the bad idea? I have a raspi, Its a fickle little thing that dosen't like sudden poweroffs, corrupts the data on the boot SD card if you look at it *funny* and in some cases its bottlenecks have bottlenecks. I run mine off an external HDD which needs a hub (after lots of testing). Its just generally not terribly reliable unless you know its quirks. You're better off getting an OpenVPN compatible router.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to consider not doing this.  If you're concerned enough about reliability to bother stress-testing it, you should really be using something within spec, designed for the purpose (product recommendations are off-topic so I won't recommend anything specific).

If you do this, you're probably going to find the device degrades faster over time and becomes unreliable, because overclocking lowers MTTF.  I doubt very much you will find any MTTF metrics for this scenario, and you can't evaluate that with a stress test.  Temperature is also not the only thing to worry about.

Comment: Problem is always the same..... I think about performance and reliability and the boss only think about budged. We can have 11 raspberry for the price of one of our current barebones. Also, some of the offices might get bigger in the future and need printer server, shared folders, etc and we will have to buy new equipment

Comment: @Santi Probably it will cost much more than 11 RPis to be down for a week because one of them died and you have to send out another one!

Comment: The idea is deploy them only on places where VPN connection is not critical and one week of downtime is acceptable.

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't do this (as many people have said). The Pi is not designed for production use. Yes, it can work and people have done it. However, the Pi is *very* sensitive to power fluctuations and other environmental hazards which makes it unreliable for anything critical. This is why it's used for education and occasionally for people to play with media libraries and the like on it.

It's your choice, but professional wisdom says absolutely not.